# c# mvc query get values with (not exists, or not in, or foreach)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a selected user attribute with this value of type int (1,2,3)
and I have my invitation order model that has users id (1,2)
I want to obtain the values that are different between both.
in this case 3.

order.userSelected has values(1,2,3)
and my invitationOrder model has (Id,IdUser,more...)

How can i do it?
I do not know how to do it prove with foreach nothing i want to obtain the values that are not in the model

```
case "newUsersToAddInvitationOrder":
foreach(var item  in order.userSelected )
{
   int id = item;// userSelected has values 1,2,3  
   //  invitationOrder has IdUser 1 and 2          
   db.InvitationOrder
       .Where(m=>m.IdOrder==order.IdOrder)
       .Where(m=>m.IdUser==id)//I want to get the value that is not in the invitation that value 3,


}
```

Comment: Show some code!

Comment: Question is a bit vague but if both those are collections you can get them by `list1?.Where(x => !list2.Contains(x))?.ToArray()`. Assuming list2 is NOT null

Comment: Please show the classes and sample data. It's very hard to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you want to do this

```
order.userSelected.Except(db.InvitationOrder.Where(m=>m.IdOrder==order.IdOrder).Select(m=>m.IdUser));
```